# Alignment of numeric values in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, nsnumber

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells.

Each of these cells has six UILabels, in which numeric values are presented (please refer to the screenshot below).

Unfortunately the numeric values in the last row are not correctly aligned. Having them right-aligned would also not be helpful. The correct alignment would be along the "," comma.

How can I comma-align numeric values in iOS? Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: why right alignment is not the correct way? in my projects that works fine.

Comment: Seems to me that right alignment would work fine to me.  You'll always have three digits to the right of each comma, so 1,234 will be aligned the same as 1,000.

Comment: Jonas & Michael, right alignment would look better, but for instance the width of "1,111" is less than "8,888". The comma for "1,111" would be positioned a bit more towards the right side than for "8,888".

Comment: really?  what font are you using?  Cartoon Sans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use right alignment with a fixed width font like Courier.